# I'm trying to auto-click a onesignal button when page load.. But not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, onesignal

How can I auto-click a 'onesignal' button when page load? I'm trying with javascript and jquery codes but it is not working.

First codes is here when page load..

```
<div id="onesignal-bell-launcher" class="onesignal-bell-launcher onesignal-bell-launcher-md onesignal-bell-launcher-bottom-right onesignal-bell-launcher-theme-default onesignal-bell-launcher-active">
    <div class="onesignal-bell-launcher-button">
        <!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
        <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
        <svg version="1.1" class="onesignal-bell-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="99.7px" height="99.7px" viewBox="0 0 99.7 99.7" style="filter: drop-shadow(0 2px 4px rgba(34,36,38,0.35));; -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 2px 4px rgba(34,36,38,0.35));;" xml:space="preserve">
            <g>
                <circle class="background" cx="49.9" cy="49.9" r="49.9"></circle>
                <g id="Layer_2">
                    <g>
                        <path class="foreground" d="M50.1,66.2H27.7c0,0-2-0.2-2-2.1c0-1.9,1.7-2,1.7-2s6.7-3.2,6.7-5.5c0-2.3-1.1-3.9-1.1-13.3
                            s6-16.6,13.2-16.6c0,0,1-2.4,3.9-2.4c2.8,0,3.8,2.4,3.8,2.4c7.2,0,13.2,7.2,13.2,16.6s-1,11-1,13.3c0,2.3,6.7,5.5,6.7,5.5
                            s1.7,0.1,1.7,2c0,1.8-2.1,2.1-2.1,2.1H50.1z"></path>
                        <path class="foreground" d="M42.9,68.5h14.5c0,0-1,6.3-7.2,6.3S42.9,68.5,42.9,68.5z"></path>
                        <ellipse class="stroke" cx="49.9" cy="49.9" rx="37.4" ry="36.9"></ellipse>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </svg>
        <div class="pulse-ring"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="onesignal-bell-launcher-badge"></div>
    <div class="onesignal-bell-launcher-message">
        <div class="onesignal-bell-launcher-message-body">Lütfen bildirimlere izin veriniz..</div>
    </div>
    <div class="onesignal-bell-launcher-dialog" style="filter: drop-shadow(0px 2px 2px rgba(34,36,38,.15));; -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 2px 2px rgba(34,36,38,.15));;">
        <div class="onesignal-bell-launcher-dialog-body">
            <h1>Site bildirimlerini yönet</h1>
            <div class="divider"></div>
            <div class="push-notification">
                <div class="push-notification-icon push-notification-icon-default"></div>
                <div class="push-notification-text-container">
                    <div class="push-notification-text push-notification-text-short"></div>
                    <div class="push-notification-text"></div>
                    <div class="push-notification-text push-notification-text-medium"></div>
                    <div class="push-notification-text"></div>
                    <div class="push-notification-text push-notification-text-medium"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="action-container">
                <button type="button" class="action" id="subscribe-button">TAKİP ET</button>
            </div>
            <div class="divider"></div>
            <div class="kickback">Powered by <a href="https://onesignal.com" class="kickback" target="_blank">OneSignal</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And second button is open when First button is clicked

```
<div class="action-container">
    <button type="button" class="action" id="subscribe-button">TAKİP ET</button>
</div>
```

Comment: please be more elaborate when you are asking questions .. **for how to ask good question please read**  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @serhatgksu: Were you happy with answer or looking for something else?

Comment: I want onesignal to automatically prompt the user to subscribe when they visit my website. How to do it?

Comment: You can view a Onesignal plugin for wordpress. He make this.
Enable the option Automatically prompt new site visitors to subscribe to push notifications.
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/wordpress
https://wordpress.org/plugins/onesignal-free-web-push-notifications

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to register an onclick event, where callback function has necessary code to add elements, and then fire a click event

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $("#subscribe-button").on("click", function() {
          $(this).parent().append("<div class="action-container"><button type="button" class="action" id="subscribe-button2">TAKİP ET</button></div>")
     });
     $("#subscribe-button").trigger('click');
});
```

Keep in mind, Here you should have different id to the second button, No 2 HTML could have same ids, If you will try to get element it will give you only first from the DOM

Comment: I want onesignal to automatically prompt the user to subscribe when they visit my website. How to do it?

Comment: @ankit : you can show one div hovering over your page  when your page loads, and there should be a button on which if user clicks, then run above code...

Comment: @Ankit Would you please elaborate? what is correct solution?

Comment: this is correct solution https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/permission-requests

Answer (score 3):

in this case you can use from jQuery. please add new js file in your document and put this code on that:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $("#ID OF YOUR BUTTON").trigger('click');
});
```

this code run when loading of your html file completed and click on button.

Comment: I want onesignal to automatically prompt the user to subscribe when they visit my website. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Browsers have a built-in popup blocker that prevents new windows from being opened when a page is loaded -- the user must first click a link or button.

Since the OneSignal button opens a popup window, the user must click it themselves for it to work.

Comment: I want onesignal to automatically prompt the user to subscribe when they visit my website. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can auto click on  button when page load. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#subscribe-button").trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not work this method. I suppose onesignal may have taken measures. My web sites is http://mucizeguvelik.com.tr, you can view for see the onesignal button code.